# How do I find local minimums in data?

Tags: data

*Mathematica* easily allows you to use `FindPeaks` to find local maxima in your data is there any equivalent function for finding local minima?

Comment: Yes: `FindPeaks[-data]` would do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = {2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 4, 7, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1};
valleys = {#,-#2} & @@@ FindPeaks[-data]
(* {{2, 1}, {9, 2}, {13, 2}, {17, 1}} *)

ListLinePlot[data, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[valleys]}]
```

[image]